# Vuex: Why is store only updated when dispatching page is refreshed?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a vue component that gathers some data that should eventually be used to update a vuex store.

On the click of a button this function is triggered:

```
    confirmResult() {
      var type = this.type;
      var value = this.max_keys_formatted.toLowerCase();
      const updateData = {
        type: type,
        value: value,
      }

      this.$store.dispatch("updateType", updateData);
      this.$router.replace("/home") //replace: no going back (as against 'push')
    },
```

In my store, the action `updateType` calls the mutation `updateType` that updates the `state` (or at least it should):

```
const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      sellerType: "initiativ",
      buyerType: "dominant",
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    updateType(state, updateData) {
      console.log("type: ", updateData.type);
      console.log("value: ", updateData.value);

      if (updateData.type == "seller") {
        console.log("now in seller");
        state.sellerType = updateData.value;
      }
      if (updateData.type == "buyer") {
        state.buyerType = updateData.value;
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {
    updateType(context, updateData) {
      context.commit("updateType", updateData); // Place to store in backend server
    }
  },
});
```

Now, when I refresh the page that contains the intially triggering button, this all works fine and my console outputs:

[image]

But when I navigate to the page that contains the intially triggering button, but do not refresh it, the output on the console remains the same, but the store is not updated!

I can't figure out why that is! If you need additional information, please let me know!

Comment: Should be working even tho, you should probably not have the same name for both mutation and action. Do you see the mutation in the Vue devtools, Vuex tab?

Comment: I was not able to get the vue devtools working yet. It says it can access the website, but that vue.js is not detected.
Giving mutation and action a different name didn't help ‍♂️

Comment: It should just not be named the same since they do different stuff. Do you run your app locally in dev mode? You should have access to the devtools if your app is not in production mode. Start by this one as it will help you debug properly. And you'll need it anyway at some point.

Comment: Yes, app is run locally in dev mode. I was able to activate dev tools 6.0.0 beta 3, but vuex seems not to be included yet.

Comment: pretty sure those devtools are for vue3, and since they are in beta, you rather use the stable one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en